# How can I center the title at the top of a printed (Ctrl+P) page? HMTL/CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

When you print a page, the browser automatically adds the title of the page to the top of the page that is to be printed. My problem is, this is not centered correctly; it is about 100px further right than I needed to be. How can I center it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open your browser's dev tools (F12) and edit the CSS directly so the print will be as you like.

It will be nice if you add an example link and screenshot of the problem so I can direct you to the solution.

Comment: that's the problem, there is no css to edit for this element. Checking view source, I only see the elements that have been written in by me. on the Ctrl+P page, I click inspect element on the title in the header of the printable page, and it just shows the element that contains the abstracted print content, like an iframe.